# How to specify the deployment order for ejb and war to deploy inside an ear?

Tags: maven, deployment, ear, ejb-3.1, jboss-eap-7

I have created a maven ear project which consists of 1 jar, 5 EJBs and 1 war.  But when I tried  to deploy it on server JBOSS EAP 7.0, the deployment order is not respected which is there in application.xml. Because of this issue, I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "ear_module.ear")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
    "jboss.module.service.\"deployment.ear_module.ear.war_module-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\".main is missing [jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.jar1.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb3.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb5.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb2.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb4.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb1.jar\".main, module.resolved.service.\"deployment.ear_module.ear.war_module-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\".main]",
    "jboss.module.resolve.phase.\"deployment.ear_module.ear\".main.1 is missing [jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.jar1.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb3.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb2.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb4.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb1.jar\".main]",
    "jboss.module.resolve.phase.\"deployment..ear.war_module-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\".main.1 is missing [jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.jar1.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb3.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb5.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb2.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb4.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb1.jar\".main]",
    "jboss.module.service.\"deployment.ear_module.ear.ejb5-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\".main is missing [jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.jar1.jar\".main, module.resolved.service.\"deployment.ear_module.ear.ejb5-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb3.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb2.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb4.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb1.jar\".main]",
    "jboss.module.resolve.phase.\"deployment.ear_module.ear.ejb5-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\".main.1 is missing [jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.jar1.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb3.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb2.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb4.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb1.jar\".main]",
    "jboss.module.resolve.phase.\"deployment.ear_module.ear.jar1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\".main.1 is missing [jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.jar1.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb3.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb2.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb4.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb1.jar\".main]",
    "jboss.module.resolve.phase.\"deployment.ear_module.ear.ejb1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\".main.1 is missing [jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.jar1.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb3.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb2.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb4.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb1.jar\".main]",
    "jboss.module.resolve.phase.\"deployment.ear_module.ear.ejb2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\".main.1 is missing [jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.jar1.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb3.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb2.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb4.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb1.jar\".main]",
    "jboss.module.resolve.phase.\"deployment.ear_module.ear.premap_execution_server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\".main.1 is missing [jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.jar1.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb3.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb2.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb4.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb1.jar\".main]",
    "jboss.module.resolve.phase.\"deployment.ear_module.ear.ejb4-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\".main.1 is missing [jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.jar1.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb3.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb2.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb4.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb1.jar\".main]",
    "jboss.module.service.\"deployment.ear_module.ear.ejb1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\".main is missing [jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.jar1.jar\".main, module.resolved.service.\"deployment.ear_module.ear.ejb1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb3.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb2.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb4.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb1.jar\".main]",
    "jboss.module.resolve.phase.\"deployment.ear_module.ear.ejb3-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\".main.1 is missing [jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.jar1.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb3.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb2.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb4.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb1.jar\".main]",
    "jboss.module.service.\"deployment.ear_module.ear.ejb3-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\".main is missing [jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.jar1.jar\".main, module.resolved.service.\"deployment.ear_module.ear.ejb3-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb3.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb2.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb4.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb1.jar\".main]",
    "jboss.module.service.\"deployment.ear_module.ear.ejb4-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\".main is missing [jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.jar1.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb3.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb2.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb4.jar\".main, module.resolved.service.\"deployment.ear_module.ear.ejb4-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb1.jar\".main]",
    "jboss.module.service.\"deployment.ear_module.ear.premap_execution_server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\".main is missing [jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.jar1.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb3.jar\".main, module.resolved.service.\"deployment.ear_module.ear.premap_execution_server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb2.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb4.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb1.jar\".main]",
    "jboss.module.service.\"deployment.ear_module.ear\".main is missing [jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.jar1.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb3.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb2.jar\".main, module.resolved.service.\"deployment.ear_module.ear\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb4.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb1.jar\".main]",
    "jboss.module.service.\"deployment.ear_module.ear.jar1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\".main is missing [jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.jar1.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb3.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb2.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb4.jar\".main, module.resolved.service.\"deployment.ear_module.ear.jar1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb1.jar\".main]",
    "jboss.module.service.\"deployment.ear_module.ear.ejb2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\".main is missing [jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.jar1.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb3.jar\".main, module.resolved.service.\"deployment.ear_module.ear.ejb2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb2.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb4.jar\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ejb1.jar\".main]"
]}
```

I have tried all the possible methods, but the problem still remains. Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong here.

Edit:
Ear pom.xml

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>Grpmodule</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
<artifactId>ear_module</artifactId>
<packaging>ear</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>Grpmodule</groupId>
        <artifactId>jar1</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>jar</type>
         <scope>provided</scope> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>Grpmodule</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb1</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
         <scope>provided</scope> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>Grpmodule</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb2</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
         <scope>provided</scope> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>Grpmodule</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb3</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
         <scope>provided</scope> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>Grpmodule</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb4</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
         <scope>provided</scope> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>Grpmodule</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb5</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
         <scope>provided</scope> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>Grpmodule</groupId>
        <artifactId>war_module</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>war</type>
         <scope>provided</scope> 
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
            <configuration>

                   <initializeInOrder>true</initializeInOrder>
                <modules>
                    <ejbModule>
                        <groupId>Grpmodule</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jar1</artifactId>
                    </ejbModule>
                    <ejbModule>
                        <groupId>Grpmodule</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ejb1</artifactId>
                    </ejbModule>
                    <ejbModule>
                        <groupId>Grpmodule</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ejb2</artifactId>
                    </ejbModule>
                    <ejbModule>
                        <groupId>Grpmodule</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ejb3</artifactId>
                    </ejbModule>
                    <ejbModule>
                        <groupId>Grpmodule</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ejb4</artifactId>
                    </ejbModule>
                    <ejbModule>
                        <groupId>Grpmodule</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ejb5</artifactId>
                    </ejbModule>
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>Grpmodule</groupId>
                        <artifactId>war_module</artifactId>
                        <uri>war_module-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war</uri>
                        <contextRoot>/application</contextRoot>
                    </webModule>
                </modules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Parent pom.xml:-

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


<groupId>Grpmodule</groupId>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>PREMAP : Parent</name>
<description>This project only contains POM which defines the dependency for the other projects which are defined as modules</description>
<contributors />
<developers />
<modules>
    <module>../jar1</module>
    <module>../ejb1</module>
    <module>../ejb2</module>
    <module>../ejb3</module>
    <module>../ejb4</module>
    <module>../ejb5</module>
    <module>../war_module</module>
    <module>../ear</module>
</modules>
```

Comment: It looks `Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [ "jboss.module.service.\"deployment.ear_module.ear.war_module-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\".main is missing [jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.jar1.jar\".main, ` your packaging is wrong...but I can only speculate cause there is no pom file etc.

Comment: Added the pom files of ear and parent

Comment: If you are using `application.xml` 6.0 schema you have an handy element named initialize-in-order which, if set to true, initializes the modules in the same order they are listed,this would resolve your issue or if you want to deploy ear's in sequence you can use`jboss-deplyment-structure.xml` and define the dependent ear as a module dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jboss-all.xml deployment descriptor file to specify dependencies. This needs to be placed under WEB-INF for war files and META-INF for EAR files.

For example, if you want JAR1 to be deployed before ejb1. Then you need to specify dependency for JAR1 in jboss-all.xml inside ejb1 and so on.

```
<jboss umlns="urn:jboss:1.0">
 <jboss-deployment-dependencies xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-dependencies:1.0">
  <dependency name="JAR1.jar" />
 </jboss-deployment-dependencies>
</jboss>
```

Comment: Please take note, this is not a for strict ordering as described in the Redhat Documentation for EAP 7:   'Although the jboss-all.xml file and other deployment descriptors allow you to declare dependencies that the server does not otherwise detect, it is not a strict ordering feature. JBoss EAP assumes that all dependencies specified in the deployment descriptor have already been deployed or are available. If there are missing dependencies, JBoss EAP does not automatically deploy them, and the deployment fails.'